# MySQL alter table enable keys not as fast as promised

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have a large table with a bit more than 2 billion records, and 5 multi-column keys.

There are two methods I can use for inserting data:

**Method 1**

```
load data infile ...;
```

**Method 2**

```
alter table disable keys;
load data infile ...;
alter table enable keys;
```

If I'm starting from an empty table, for 2 billion records, method 1 takes about 60 hours (estimated, may be more), while method 2 takes 12 hours to insert the data, and 3 hours recreating the keys. So far so good.

However, if I already have my 2 billion records, and attempt to insert an additional 5 million, method 1 takes about 3 hours, while method 2 takes 30 minutes inserting the data, and a whopping 7 hours recreating the keys. I confirmed that during the entire key regeneration, it used `Repair by sorting`, so it's not like it fell back to `Repair with keycache`.

I wonder why this is. MySQL claims that disabling keys is very good for inserting bulk data, but this is obviously dependent on the context. If it is about to regenerate all keys from scratch, why doesn't it take around 3 hours, as when I started with an empty table? or if it inserts keys one by one, why doesn't it take around 3 hours, which is what it took for method 1?

Comments are welcome

Comment: I up-voted your question because I think it is very valid, yet hasn't been answered so far. FYI There is a mistake in your second method, you meant to "enable keys".

Answer (score 1):

The time taken can vary quite a bit apparently.

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/07/05/working-with-large-data-sets-in-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with billions of records, and using MySQL 5.1 or above, then you might find [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/performance-partitioning.html) will benefit performance... when working with indexes in a partitioned table, indexes are also partitioned; and because each index is only built against a partitiion/subset of your total data, the sorting overheads of rebuilding should be significantly less.

Comment: Thank you, I know how partitioning works. My question is not how to solve a problem, but why does MySQL behaves in this way.

Answer (score 0):

"not as fast as promised" - uh, you have 5000000 records, of course it will take *a bit* longer than inserting 20 records.

- With the first method, it is changing the indexes a little bit on every row insert, so they are always consistent with the data.
- With the second method, it is rebuilding the indexes **by sorting the whole table** (2005000000 rows) - which means it's moving a large amount of *existing* index data to and fro (disk speed is a likely to emerge as a bottleneck here), which depends on 1) amount of existing data, and 2) amount of new data.
- You could use method 3: **drop keys** before the second insert (this could take some time, too) and recreate them afterwards. I suspect the time will be similar to recreating the keys after the initial insert

The speeds you are describing are quite reasonable IMHO - just use the fastest method.

Comment: I never claimed it should be fast, I only said it's not as fast as advertised. MySQL's documentation says "ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE KEYS tells MySQL to stop updating nonunique indexes. ALTER TABLE ... ENABLE KEYS then should be used to re-create *missing* indexes. MySQL does this with a special algorithm that is much faster than inserting keys one by one." But it is obviously not. Finally, dropping keys and adding them require an entire table copy each, which `ENABLE KEYS` doesn't. If it's going to recreate the entire index, I see no good reason to do as you propose.

Comment: @Oscar Rodriguez: Good points. As I said, I suspect that recreating the missing keys causes a lot of shuffling of the existing keys back and forth, causing the slowdown.